# What is the SE website to ask about computer networking?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What is the SE website to discuss about the theoretic side of computer networking?

as far as I know, Stack-overflow discussing about the "real" side of computer networking, about application using that etc.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of a question?

Comment: If it's a programming-related question, perhaps http://programmers.stackexchange.com or http://stackoverflow.com would be suitable. If it's not a question about programming, then it might be on-topic on http://serverfault.com or http://superuser.com.

Comment: Post the example question here

Comment: Your question is too broad and there are too many answers possible. Please edit your question and give more information about it.